# Dictionary listing case for verbs

Tags: глаголы, падежи

Is there a dictionary that lists the case that precedes, succeeds verbs? For example идти (accusative) - Я хочу идти в Россию; быть (past, instrumental) - Я был собакой.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/глагольного-управления-иностранцев-электронное-сертификационный-ebook/dp/B0184KH8AM

Answer (score 2):

Russian dictionaries use question words such as **кого-чего, кем-чем** to indicate the grammatical case:

> ГОРДИТЬСЯ кем-чем / (разг.) за кого.

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=гордиться&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x)

The dictionary «Управление в русском языке» specifically addresses verb government.

The Russian Wiktionary lists cases for some verbs:

> Участники ситуации, описываемой с помощью **мешать**:
>
> 1. субъект (им. п.),
> 2. объект (вин. п.),
> 3. инструмент (твор. п.).

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/мешать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: This. There's also "Толково-комбинаторный словарь" but it might be... taxing for non-native speakers.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than approaching it comprehensively, I wonder if you might just get familiar with the exceptions to the verb → accusative direct object correspondence, as a majority of verbs you encounter in the wild conform to this pattern.

[This post](http://masterrussian.net/f15/list-verbs-require-dative-genitive-instrumental-case-20791/) is one such attempt to catalogue these exceptions.